# Image converter for classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to convert images for classification but can't find the soultion.

The actual code converts one picture and not an entire folder. Is there any soultion to read all images from folder "images" and convert them into folder "output" with the skeletal structure?

Many thanks in advance.

Alexander

```
import logging
import time
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

from tf_pose.estimator import TfPoseEstimator
from tf_pose.networks import get_graph_path, model_wh
import scripts.label_image as label_img
import scripts.label_image_scene as label_img_scene

logger = logging.getLogger('Pose_Action_and_Scene_Understanding')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] [%(name)s] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

fps_time = 0
address = os.getcwd()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='tf-classification')
    parser.add_argument('--image', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--show-process', type=bool, default=False,
                        help='for debug purpose, if enabled, speed for inference is dropped.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    logger.debug('initialization %s : %s' % ('mobilenet_thin', get_graph_path('mobilenet_thin')))
    e = TfPoseEstimator(get_graph_path('mobilenet_thin'), target_size=(432, 368))
    image = cv2.imread(args.image)
    logger.info('cam image=%dx%d' % (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))
    
    logger.debug('+image processing+')
    logger.debug('+postprocessing+')
    start_time = time.time()
    humans = e.inference(image, upsample_size=4.0)
    img = TfPoseEstimator.draw_humans(image, humans, imgcopy=False)
    
    logger.debug('+classification+')
    # Getting only the skeletal structure (with white background) of the actual image
    image = np.zeros(image.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
    image.fill(255) 
    image = TfPoseEstimator.draw_humans(image, humans, imgcopy=False)
    
    cv2.imwrite('show1.png',image)
    cv2.imshow('tf-classification', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    logger.debug('+finished+')
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

depending how your data is organized you can use the the ImageDataGenerator to augment your images. Then use .flow or .flow_from_directory to save the transformed images to a directory you specify. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)